# Polynomial of degree four of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Given $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ Find a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree three such that $P^{(k)}(4)=f^{(k)}(4)$ for $k=0,1,2,3,4$.

I know this has to do with Extended mean value theorem, or, Taylor Formula. However, I am unable to approach it.

Comment: Do you mean by $P^k$ the $k$th power or the derivative of $P$?

Comment: Sorry, it's $k^{th}$ derivative

Comment: So you must edit $P^{(k)}$

Comment: and that was polynomial of degree four. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$c_k=f^{(k)}(4),k=0,\ldots,4,$$
then by Taylor theorem we have
$$P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^4 \frac{P^{(k)}(4)}{k!}(x-4)^4=\sum_{k=0}^4 \frac{c_k}{k!}(x-4)^4,$$
is a polynomial of degre 4 verify $P^{(k)}(4)=f^{(k)}(4)$.